# scala spark dataframe explode is slow - so, alternate method - create columns and rows from arrays in a column

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, rdd, user-defined-functions

Scala 2.11.8, spark 2.0.1

The explode function is very slow - so, looking for an alternate method.  I think it is possible with RDD's with flatmap - and, help is greatly appreciated.

I have an udf that returns List(String, String, String, Int) of varying lengths.  For each row in the dataframe, I want to create multiple rows, and make multiple columns.

```
def Udf = udf ( (s: String ) => {
   if (s=="1") Seq(("a", "b", "c", 0), ("a1", "b1", "c1", 1), ("a2", "b2", "c2", 2)).toList   
       else Seq(("a", "b", "c", 0)).toList
})

val df = Seq(("a", "1"), ("b", "2")).toDF("A", "B")
val df1 = df.withColumn("C", Udf($"B"))
val df2 = df1.select($"A", explode($"C"))
val df3 = df2.withColumn("D", $"col._1").withColumn("E", $"col._2").withColumn("F", $"col._3").withColumn("G", $"col._4")

/// dataframe after going through udf
+---+---+--------------------+
|  A|  B|                   C|
+---+---+--------------------+
|  a|  1|[[a,b,c,0], [a1,b...|
|  b|  2|         [[a,b,c,0]]|
+---+---+--------------------+

///Final dataframe
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
|  A|         col|  D|  E|  F|  G|
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
|  a|   [a,b,c,0]|  a|  b|  c|  0|
|  a|[a1,b1,c1,1]| a1| b1| c1|  1|
|  a|[a2,b2,c2,2]| a2| b2| c2|  2|
|  b|   [a,b,c,0]|  a|  b|  c|  0|
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
```

This is very slow on many millions of rows.  Takes over 12 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another simple example:

```
val ds = sc.parallelize(Seq((0, "Lorem ipsum dolor", 1.0, Array("prp1", "prp2", "prp3"))))
```

Alternative way of exploding arrays using flatMaps.

```
ds.flatMap { t => 
  t._4.map { prp => 
    (t._1, t._2, t._3, prp) }}.collect.foreach(println)
```

Result:

```
(0,Lorem ipsum dolor,1.0,prp1)
(0,Lorem ipsum dolor,1.0,prp2)
(0,Lorem ipsum dolor,1.0,prp3)
```

Tried with your dataset but not sure if its the optimal way of doing it.

```
df1.show(false)

+---+---+------------------------------------------------+
|A  |B  |C                                               |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------+
|a  |1  |[[a, b, c, 0], [a1, b1, c1, 1], [a2, b2, c2, 2]]|
|b  |2  |[[a, b, c, 0]]                                  |
+---+---+------------------------------------------------+


df1.rdd.flatMap { t:Row => t.getSeq(2).map { row: Row => (t.getString(0),t.getString(1),row)}}
.map {
    case (col1: String,col2: String, col3: Row) => (col1, col2,col3.getString(0),col3.getString(1),col3.getString(2),col3.getInt(3))
  }.collect.foreach(println)
```

Result:

```
(a,1,a,b,c,0)
(a,1,a1,b1,c1,1)
(a,1,a2,b2,c2,2)
(b,2,a,b,c,0)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: When I use your technique, e.g. df1.rdd.flatMap { t => t._3.map { prp => (t._1, t._2, prp)}}.collect -- I am getting an error --  error: value _3 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Comment: Please run the code above till df1.  The critical function is the explode in the next line, which takes a lot of time.  If you can work with df1, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  If you have time to resolve, I am getting an error: It starts with  error: not found: type Row and goes on to value getInt is not a member of Any.   If not, this is extremely helpful.

Comment: You have already solved the problem as defined above.  However, this solution does not work with my Spark/ Scala version (when I copy everything exactly as provided).  For some reason, my interpreter is refusing to interpret df1.rdd as RDD[Row] - even though it shows up as  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] .  I am solving exactly the problem above.

Comment: You have imported all these three right?                                    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

Comment: It worked.  Thank you for working with me patiently.  I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Update Spark to version 2.3 or later where [SPARK-21657](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657) should be fixed.
- Replace your code with `flatMap`:

  ```
  df.as[(String, String)].flatMap { 
    case (a, "1") => Seq(
      (a, "a", "b", "c", 0), (a, "a1", "b1", "c1", 1), 
      (a, "a2", "b2", "c2", 2)
    )
    case (a, _) => Seq((a, "a", "b", "c", 0))
  }
  ```

Comment: I cannot  upgrade from Spark 2.0+ or Scala 2.11.8.  Also, the list returned from the udf is of varying length (could be from 1 to 100+).  So, using case statements in this way is not a feasible approach.