# Scala dataframe - where is the spark/ scala dataframe source code for explode on github

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, dataframe, explode

As explained in [this article](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657), [Explode is slow in scala 2.11.8 and spark 2.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376257/scala-spark-dataframe-explode-is-slow-so-alternate-method-create-columns-an).  Without moving to higher spark versions, alternate methods to improve it are also slow.  Since the issue has been fixed in later versions of spark, one approach would be to copy the fixed source code. In looking for the source code, [I found a reference to explode in functions, but, I do not know how to track the function further](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala).  How would I find the source code for working Explode in new spark source code - so, I can use it instead of the current version of explode?

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Explode.scala

Comment: @Chitral, I did not find Explode.scala at https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions (or in many of the sub-folders and one folder up that I looked).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/generators.scala is the link I think you're looking for

I was able to find it by expanding all the `import org.apache._` imports within https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala after seeing that the explode function there was just `def explode(e: Column): Column = withExpr { Explode(e.expr) }`

if you wanted to import the underlying Explode function, I believe the direct import would be `import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Explode`